# How do I convert apply(map, args) to map(function, iterable) in this case?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I downloaded a MultiListBox widget, and a sorting extension to it that I successfully applied. However, this widget has never worked for me in python 3. The libraries are Tkinter (py2) and tkinter (py3).

So, I've been getting it closer and closer to working, but there's a part that I'm not quite understanding how to get past. The `apply()` function is deprecated, and, it would seem, not even in py3. So be it.

This is what I don't understand:

We've got `apply(function, args [, keywords])` and `map(function, iterable...)`

The `apply()` function gets called like:

`return apply(map, [None] + result)` (result is a list of tuples of strings)

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply) suggests I take the approach of converting `apply(function, *args, **keywords)` to `function(*args, **keywords)`. This is all well and good, but I can't figure out what to pass as the new function.

`return map(what_am_i, result)`

Here are some relevant code snippets. Hope this is all clear, but feel free to ask for more. Thanks.

I've added some more code to provide a context for what's going on here. Perhaps that will generate some insights that will make this code more `beautiful`?

In this example, the `result` contains a `list` of length 3 (columns), of `1000-tuples` (rows). Each element of those `1000-tuples` is a `string` containing either a `Subject`, `Sender`, or `Date`.

I've now updated with the complete _sort() function.

Now, I've updated with the other instance of refactoring apply() out. I might as well figure this thing out into this question so everyone else can enjoy.

```
from tkinter import *

class MultiListbox(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, rowslist):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.rowslist = []
        self.colmapping = {}
        self.origData = None
        for (row, colwidth) in rowslist:
            frame = Frame(self);
            b = Button(frame, ...)
            b.bind(...)
            listbox = Listbox(frame, ...)
            self.rowslist.append(listbox)
            listbox.bind(...)
            ...
        ...
    ...
    def _scroll(self, *args):
        for row in self.rowslist:
            row.yview(None, args)
            # apply(row.yview, args)
    ...
    def get(self, first, last=None):
        result = []
        for row in self.rowslist:
            result.append(row.get(first,last))
        if last:
            return map(None, result)
            #return apply(map, [None] + result)
        return result
    ...
    def _sort(self, e):
        # get the listbox to sort by (mapped by the header button)
        b=e.widget
        col, direction = self.colmapping[b]     

        # get the entire table data into mem
        tableData = self.get(0,END)
        if self.origData == None:
            import copy
            self.origData = copy.deepcopy(tableData)

        rowcount = len(tableData)

        #remove old sort indicators if it exists
        for btn in self.colmapping:
            lab = btn.cget('text')
            if lab[0]=='<': btn.config(text=lab[4:])

        btnLabel = b.cget('text')
        #sort data based on direction
        if direction==0:
            tableData = self.origData
        else:
            if direction==1: b.config(text='<+> ' + btnLabel)
            else: b.config(text='<-> ' + btnLabel)
            # sort by col
            tableData.sort(key=lambda x: x[col], reverse=direction<0)

        #clear widget
        self.delete(0,END)

        # refill widget
        for row in range(rowcount):
            self.insert(END, tableData[row])

        # toggle direction flag
        if direction == 1:
            direction = -1
        else:
            direction = direction + 1

        self.colmapping[b] = (col, direction)
        # =:> End of complete _sort(self, e) <:= #
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk = Tk()
    Label(tk, text='SortableMultiListbox').pack()
    mlb = MultiListbox(tk, (('Subject', 40), ('Sender', 20), ('Date', 10)))
    for i in range(1000):
        mlb.insert(END, ('Important Message: %d' % i, 'John Doe', '10/10/%04d' % (1900+i)))
    mlb.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
    tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
apply(map, [None] + result)
```

is equivalent to

```
map(*[None] + result)
```

or, perhaps more readably,

```
map(None, *result)
```

Note that if you want a transpose, it's probably better to use `zip(*result)`:

```
>>> # Usually the same behavior:
... result = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> map(None, *result)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> zip(*result)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> # But if result has only one iterable in it:
... result = [[1, 2, 3]]
>>> map(None, *result)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> zip(*result)
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
```

Comment: Ahhahah .. I love it. That's why I couldn't figure out what function to put in there: I should pass no function at all. Very pythonic. Thanks.

Comment: a better question may be why would you do this?

Comment: @Inversus: Note: If you want a transpose operation, consider `zip(*result)`. It mostly does the same thing, but people will recognize it more easily, and it does something more reasonable in the case where `result` only contains one iterable.

Comment: @user2357112 That's very interesting about zip(), do you think I could use it in my use case? Would it crash if there were only 1 row in the rowslist variable? I've edited my question with new code and a section of text right above the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JoranBeasley To answer the question of why I am doing it this way: I'm not sure. It wasn't my code to begin with. lol. It's the getter for a list of the rows contained in the MultiListBox. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Inversus: Looks like `zip` would be appropriate. Depending on how much you understand this code, it may or may not be worth changing.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Actually, if you could answer that question ("why would you do this?"), I'd be grateful. It seems quite strange to map a result set to no function and return it..

Comment: The plot thickens: `...in _sort \n rowcount = len(tableData) \n TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()` I'll update my code in the question.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm looking to understand it completely, and use it with impunity! lol. I've `encountered an error` using this approach. I've posted the _sort() function, if you've got a sec?

Comment: I got past that error by using zip(), but I think I've run into the situation you warned me about, as my dataset is truncated to 3 items (the size of the list)... and past that one. I'm just updating the question as I go.